# Hide one element and show another on hover

Tags: html, css

I want the first of the two < i > elements to be shown when not hovering and the other one to be hidden, and when hovering I want the other way around. Is that possible with CSS or do I need to use JS?

```
<a class="btn btn-like postb2" href="#">
    <i class="sprite-io sprite-like-grey"></i>
    <i class="sprite-io sprite-like-white"></i>
    3
</a>
```

Comment: selecting previous sibling element is not possible in css. but there may be a other way around.

Comment: you only show 2 `i` elements and say they are shown when not hover, but yet say you want the other one hidden, which other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have an idea of what you want, and it is in fact feasible in CSS alone.

If you want to show a different sprite when hovering the anchor-tag, I would go about creating the markup a bit differently.

```
<a class="btn btn-like postb2" href="#">
    <i class="sprite-io sprite-like"></i>
    3
</a>
```

Instead of switching between two HTML-nodes, you would probably just want to change the coordinates of what to show in your CSS-sprite:

```
.postb2 .sprite-like{
    background-position: -80px -80px; // just some arbitrary coordinates for example purposes
}

.postb2:hover .sprite-like{
    background-position: -160px -160px;
}
```

Another note:

I see that you're using the names "sprite-like-grey" and "sprite-like-white". I would avoid naming my css-rules after how they appear at a certain point, and rather name them after what they actual are or perform in the application.

Answer (score 6):

```
.postb2 .sprite-like-grey,
.postb2:hover .sprite-like-white {
    display: none;
}
.postb2:hover .sprite-like-grey {
    display: inline;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YrJFE/)

You can change it to suit your HTML (btw. I don't see three `i` in your code)

Answer (score 1):

Know that's there is already the best answer for your case, but there's something I just discover about your question and Mr_Green comment which might be usefull.

You can indeed target sibling elems in CSS with combinators using `+` if the elems are next to each others or `~` if no (they need to be in the same parent).

[Little Fiddle to show](http://jsfiddle.net/4UzWm/)

[More info on W3C Website](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#combinators)